# Mixing MVC and Web API within a single entity

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET. I started working on my own project to get some experience through coding. I know that mixing MVC and Web API in a single project is a common practice and actually recommended by lots of developers. But I'd like to mix them in a specific way - here's an example:

I want to give my users an opportunity to publish posts (similar to Facebook, Twitter etc.). I have a post model and I want to implement basic CRUD operations with some simple logic behind it (eg. user cannot delete posts published by someone else). I'd like to implement C and U operations with MVC (using form built on separate site), but I want R and D implemented using Web API - the reason behind that is, I want to use JS and AJAX calls to dynamically change the DOM  instead of reloading the page every time after user clicks "Delete" button. I also want to load only first 5 posts on a display page and provide a button to load more if user wants to - without actually refreshing the page.

So my question is: Is it generally a good practice to mix these two within a single entity (a single table in database, not sure how to call that)? If not - what other solutions would you recommend me? Or maybe I totally misunderstood MVC and Web API concepts? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you do it? Yes. Should you do it? That's not on topic for discussion on Stack Overflow.

Comment: MVC and WebApi are network access API.  I don't know why *an entity* would have anything to do with *how* someone accesses the entity.  If you need to deliver an entity with html, MVC provides better mechanisms around delivering html.  WebApi on the other hand, is about delivering an entity in a data format (like JSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is.  You could have an MVC controller for your Creates and Updates, and an API controller for the Reads and Deletes.  It's not relevant that these interact with the same entity (model) in the database.

What I would suggest is performing business logic through a service for that entity, rather than having it repeated on both controllers.  Inject an instance of that service into both controller's constructors and interact with the model that way.